# Aria templates - Call service via POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, ariatemplates

I want to send via post json data.

I read the API docs ([working in an asynchronous world](http://ariatemplates.com/usermanual/latest/working_in_an_asynchronous_world) and [API doc IOAsyncRequestCfg](http://ariatemplates.com/aria/guide/apps/apidocs/#aria.core.CfgBeans:IOAsyncRequestCfg) ) and they said that it should be send like this:

```
  /* called when the template has been successfully rendered. */
    $viewReady : function(){
        console.log("$viewReady");

        var pnr = this.data.pnr;
        var names = this.data.names;
    var namesResults = [];

    if (names.length > 0) 
    {
        var monto = this.callAjaxService('https://localhost/Service1.asmx/SetNames?jsonp=false', names);//REST service
    }               
   },
```

And the call to the service is:

```
callAjaxService : function (urlString, data) {
    console.log("callAjaxService");  
    console.log(urlString);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));  
    aria.core.IO.asyncRequest({
        url : urlString,
        timeout : 10000,
        async: true,
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),  
        contentType: "application/json",
        callback : {
            fn : this.onSuccessId,
            scope : this,
            onerror : this.onError,
            onerrorScope : this
        }
    });
},
```

I think that the request it is not getting out of aria templates the request never arrives to the server. Because the response that i get is:

> error:"error"
>   errorText:"Error #2048"
>   errorType:"securityError" 
>   reqId:249
>   responseText:"undefined"
>   status:0
>   statusText:"xdr:error"

I 'm debugging the service on IIS and it never arrives there. I 've tested the service with other client and it works.

New approach, a partner told me that:

> When CORS is enabled, you can use a regular transport, based on XHR.
>   In order to tell Aria Templates to do so, you can execute this code
>   before any cross domain request:
>
> aria.core.IO.updateTransports({ 'crossDomain':
>   'aria.core.transport.XHR' });
>
> Also, due to the way CORS works to control what HTTP headers can be
>   added to a request by the client, you should also execute this code:
>
> aria.core.IO.useXHRHeader = false;

Adding those two lines to the request made it work the request arrives to the server. But, now we are getting this  response of the service

```
error:"13030"    
reqId: 255    
responseText:""    
responseXML:null    
status:13030
url:"https://localhost/Service1.asmx/GetNames?jsonp=true&callback=pol
```

The response of the server is a JSON structure. We are working on how to get the right response.

Comment: Looks like a cross domain error. Have you configured IIS for CORS?

Comment: yes yes... i 've a new good approach given by a partner (@Yannick) i ll post it here. It's almost done but we are still having problems this time with the response...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New approach was the solution. A partner told me that:

> When CORS is enabled, you can use a regular transport, based on XHR.
>   In order to tell Aria Templates to do so, you can execute this code
>   before any cross domain request:
>
> aria.core.IO.updateTransports({ 'crossDomain':
>   'aria.core.transport.XHR' });
>
> Also, due to the way CORS works to control what HTTP headers can be
>   added to a request by the client, you should also execute this code:
>
> aria.core.IO.useXHRHeader = false;

Adding those two lines to the request made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.ariatemplates.com/atlatest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myContainer"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    aria.core.IO.asyncRequest({
        url : 'http://httpbin.org/post',
        method : "post",
        callback : {
            fn : function (response, args) {
                console.log('response:', response);
            },
            scope : this
        }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Facu_Tkaczyszyn thanks that's a good way to know all the log :)